# Why do only some tags indent in html?

Tags: vimrc

If I have a `<table>` element it indents

[image: table>]

However, if I do the same thing with a `<p>` tag, it does not indent:

[image]

Why the difference here? Is there a way I can get it to indent equally after every html/xml tag? (for example, like it does for the `table` item)?

Comment: Your second question is addressed here (defining indents for a given tag...there's no "all tags do this" option, though): `:h html-indent`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The authors of the HTML indentation script shipped by Vim seem to have decided not to indent inside tags such as `<p>` because they are "self-closing" tags, meaning that the closing `</p>` is optional. I imagine the rationale for that is that, if a `</p>` was omitted by the user, the indentation wouldn't have been retracted, so each new paragraph would get indented further and further.

See [this comment](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/v8.2.0/runtime/indent/html.vim#L217-L220) in `$VIMRUNTIMES/indent/html.vim`:

> Self-closing tags and tags that are sometimes self-closing (e.g., `<p>`) are not here (when encountering `</p>` we can find the matching `<p>`, but not the other way around).
>
> Known self-closing tags: `p`, `img`, `source`, `area`, `keygen`, `track`, `wbr`.

You can override this behavior and extend the list of tags that increment indentation by setting the `g:html_indent_inctags` to a comma-separated list of additional tags that should require indentation.

In your case:

```
let g:html_indent_inctags = 'p'
```